# FCM foreground notification received, but application is not opening on Click

Tags: android, xamarin, background, firebase-cloud-messaging, foreground

First of all, I am developing an app in C# Xamarin.form. But any advice not related to Xamarin is welcome as well.

As described in the title, I am able to receive notifications no matter when the app is in background, foreground or killed.

But the problem is that I can't open (re-activate would be the better word) the app (let's say I hit android home button) when I click the foreground-received notification. Otherwise, things are all working as expected.

The server sends FCM with `notification` and `data`;

```json
{
    data: {
        topic : "push",
        title : subject,
        body : contents,
        ...data,
    },
    priority : "high",
    notification: {
        title: subject,
        body: contents,
    },
    tokens,
};
```

```
{
// [FirebaseMessagingService]
var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, MainActivity.CHANNEL_ID)
                                      .SetContentTitle(title)                         
                                      .SetContentText(messageBody)
                                      .SetPriority((int)NotificationPriority.Max)
                                      .SetAutoCancel(true)
                                      .SetContentIntent(StartActivity(url))
                                      .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Mipmap.icon)
                                      .SetStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().BigText(messageBody));

            var timeSpan = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0));
            var timestamp = timeSpan.TotalSeconds;
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
            notificationManager.Notify((int)timestamp, notificationBuilder.Build());
}

public PendingIntent StartActivity(string _url)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.instance, typeof(FCMReceiver));
            //Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.instance, typeof(MainActivity));
            //MainActivity.instance.Intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);

            MainActivity.instance.Intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            MainActivity.instance.Intent.SetAction("notification_cancelled");
            MainActivity.instance.Intent.PutExtra("url", _url);



            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            intent.SetAction("notification_cancelled");
            intent.PutExtra("url", _url);
            //DataManager.RedirectUrl = _url;
            var timeSpan = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0));
            var timestamp = timeSpan.TotalSeconds;


            return PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(MainActivity.instance, (int) timestamp, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);
            //return PendingIntent.GetActivity(MainActivity.instance, 5000, intent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);
        }
```

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = false)]
    public class FCMReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context _context, Intent intent)
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                // .. does nothing 
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unclear what part of your code actually doesn't work. Is it because your BroadcastReceiver isn't triggered, or is it something else?

Comment: First of all, sorry that I wasn't clear about the problem. It triggers all as I expected either app is on background/killed/foreground (so all FCM are received well!). But the problem is this situation that I received the "foreground-FCM" and I touched the home button and let the app backgrounded (the "foreground-FCM still remains on top status bar"), I hit that "foreground-FCM", it won't re-open back the application. But once I manually re-open the app, it triggers what it was supposed to be done.

Comment: Try to touch the home button first and make the application run in the background, then click "foreground-FCM".

Comment: @WenxuLi-MSFT that's the bug. 
Hitting the home button while application is running, and then click the 'foreground-FCM'. I expected the application to be opened, but the application didn't show back. (but the notification on the top status bar did disappear)

Comment: Where did you find it is a bug？